Browser error running Jupyter Notebook in Windows 11 Powershell
I'm having some issues running Jupyter notebooks. Recently after running 'jupyter notebook' or 'jupyter lab' in Windows 11 PowerShell, it seemed to load correctly, but Firefox then gave me the error

Firefox can’t find the file at
C:/Users/[USER]/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-44120-open.html.

I get the same error when I copy and paste the URL into Google Chrome. I can still access the notebook with the alternative URLs that are provided in PowerShell (like 'http://localhost:8888/?token=...').
Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Any help would be appreciated!

https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html
